# .NET module does not handle non-aspx requests

Tags: .net, iis-7, web-config

I have a problem I have been struggling with for some time. I have a module
that I am using for custom redirects. The idea is that if a user makes a request
and gets a 404, the error is handled through my module, a lookup is done in a database table,
and if a redirect is found for the requested URL, the user is redirected.

The problem is that this does not work for requests that do not end in .aspx.
I am running the application in integrated mode, and I thought that in integrated mode
all requests went through the pipeline and were processed by modules.

The really strange thing though is that the BeginRequest function of my modules DOES get
fired for these requests (as well as the corresponding function in global.asax), but the
error functions don't get fired.

In my web.config file, I have runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests set to true. My version
of .NET is 4.0 and my version of IIS is 7.0.